# Java - Reading multiple console input strings into a variable

Tags: java, input

I've searched around and can't find a solution to my problem. For one of my courses I'm tasked with writing a simple console email system. When the user is prompted for a message body, the string variable that holds the input only takes one word, not the whole message. I read that I should use readLine(), but when the program prompts the user to enter a message body, it completely skips input for that segment. To remedy this, I read that I should place a skip("\n") before I read the line. Now, however, the program doesn't end after the user presses Enter. It just keeps taking input and won't let me do anything.

Here is a bit of the code to help:

```
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            //Declare variables
            String subject, reciepent, message = "";
            //Get subject
            System.out.println("> Enter subject: ");
            subject = in.next();
            //Get reciepent
            System.out.println("> Enter reciepent: ");
            reciepent = in.next();
            //Get message
            System.out.println("> Enter message: ");
            in.skip("\n");
            message = in.nextLine();
            //Print out message to verify user input
            System.out.println("> " + message);
```

I don't understand how nextLine() works for all the threads I searched, but not for me.

Comment: So right after `recipent = in.next();` put a `in.nextLine();` and see if that helps. Also im quite sure you can get rid of `in.skip("\n");` unless you have that there for a reason.

Comment: Its because `next()` does not consume the newline, see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem is not to use the `.skip()` method, but use `.nextLine()` instead, which removes the trailing '\n' character from the input stream as you desire.

So change the line: `in.skip("\n");` to `in.nextLine();`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `nextLine()` which waits for user input and then returns the input. Your code should be like this:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
//Declare variables
String subject, recipient, message;
//Get subject
System.out.println("> Enter subject: ");
subject = in.nextLine();
//Get recipient
System.out.println("> Enter reciepent: ");
recipient = in.nextLine();
//Get message
System.out.println("> Enter message: ");
message = in.nextLine();
//Print out message to verify user input
System.out.println("> " + message);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

String line = "";

while((line = s.nextLine()) != null) {

   System.out.println("> Enter subject: ");

subject = in.nextLine();

//Get recipient
System.out.println("> Enter reciepent: ");
recipient = in.nextLine();

//Get message
System.out.println("> Enter message: ");
message = in.nextLine();

//Print out message to verify user input
System.out.println("> " + message);

}
```